# Why is probability taught after a first course in calculus?

Tags: calculus, probability

I don't understand why no probability textbook ever teaches probability density function or distribution function in conjunction with calculus. These topics are treated separately and no efforts are made to link between the two.

Does there exist something that combines calculus (as taught through Stewart's textbook) and probability (Sheldon Ross or Leon Garcia) and make the relationship clear? I want to understand probability from purely a geometric perspective via multiple integration, divergence and stokes theorem, is this not possible?

Also, are there any problems in probability that cannot be solved using rudimentary results from single or multivariable calculus (not analysis)

Thanks

Comment: Probability through the divergence theorem and Stokes' theorem?  What exactly do you have in mind?

Comment: Like probability current in quantum mechanics

Comment: Check out Apostol's Calculus Volume II

Comment: Stewart's book *has* a section on applications of integration to probability theory, although I think it's too brief to really give a good impression of the role of calculus in probability.  Also, probability treated properly is a whole course on its own, so it's not practical to merge it together with a first calculus course, but it is common to have it be a course that comes immediately after learning some calculus. As for "any" problems in probability not accessible by elementary methods, the list is huge; look up Brownian motion or stochastic differential equations. The subject is vast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even the definition of a general probability space requires more than rudimentary single of multivariable calculus. The usual (Kolmogorov) axiomatization is that a probability space is a measure space of total measure $1$. While not a very complicated notion, it is not rudimentary. Further, the general tools of analysis one requires for dealing with probability spaces are thus essentially measure theoretic.

It is possible to tackle some aspects of probability theory using elementary counting and/or analysis. I don't know of a book that develops things in tandem.